# Make WKWebView persist in background while another view is shown

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uitabbarcontroller, wkwebview

I'm working on an iOS Swift app with multiple views accessible via a tab bar at the bottom. One of my tabs loads a web view that plays an embedded YouTube video inline. I need this video to continue playing as the user switches between the tabs on the bottom tab bar. The state of the web view is maintained when switching between tabs, but the video will not play unless the view is actually on screen. How can I keep my WKWebView "active" while another view is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have your WKWebView's `loadHTMLString` call in `viewDidAppear`, you're probably calling `loadHTMLString` every time you dismiss the view you've just come from clearing your WKWebView.

So maybe add a boolean which you set to true when the view first appears, then add an if statement to see if its true, if it is, return and **dont** call `loadHTMLString`